# Handling Deletes in Informatica Based on Constraints

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a Scenario where I have to Do deletes in target table , But this target table has Parent Child relationship with other 3 Hierarchy Tables , Hierarchy 1 , Hierarchy 2 and Hierarchy 3 tables for example . I will only be able to Delete records from my target table after the child records in the Hierarchy tables are removed and the Delete order should be as shown below :

Hierarchy 1 --> Hierarchy 2 --> Hierarchy 3 --> Final Target Table.

How can this be handled in Informatica mapping Using Update Strategy ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually (depending on the database) I'd have a FK constraint defined with "on delete cascade" setting enabled. Implmentation details will vary depending on your DB vendor.

In case when the above is not possible, you will need to manually fetch all parents and perform a step-by-step deletion in tables in the appropriate order.

Comment: we don't have  "on delete cascade" Defined in our Database , we are using oracle DB for your information .